# Determining if Layer is Point using Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I have been working on a Python toolbox which contains 6 parameters. I am a little lost on all of the different data types available in ArcMap (it seems like there's *hundreds* of them!). However, one of the input parameters has a file extension of .shp (shapefile). I have always used the GPFeatureLayer data type and it has always worked for everything else I hope to do with my tool, although I don't completely understand why. I have only been doing my testing with point shapefiles for the time being.

What I would ultimately hope to do is check if the user has entered a shapefile that is not a point (or a collection of points). If it is not a point, throw a warning to the user, but still allow them to use the tool. From what I understand, you can check the shape type by utilizing the [Describe() class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Describe/018v00000066000000/). However, when I attempt to pass my parameter into Describe (in order to return a Describe object), ArcMap throws an error:

[image]

Here is how I define the parameter I am focusing on:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

    # First parameter = layer with customized features
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Source layer with customized features",
        name = "source",
        datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")
```

And I was hoping to throw the warning in the updateParameters() method:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    if parameters[2].value == True:
        parameters[3].enabled = True
        parameters[4].enabled = True
        parameters[5].enabled = True

    else:       
        parameters[3].enabled = False
        parameters[4].enabled = False
        parameters[5].enabled = False       

    describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0])
    if describe.shapeType == 'Point':
        arcpy.AddWarning('Warning: This is a point shapefile')
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Am I using the correct data type?

I have tried using other data types for this parameter, such as DEFeatureClass, GPPoint, and DEShapefile, but I received the following error if I tried adding my shapefile in as my parameter:

[image]

The error was the same regardless of which of the three I used.

---

My issue with the Describe() class has been cleared up by adding the .value extension in my updateParameters() method:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].value)
```

However, now when I attempt to use the setWarningMessage() function, I get no response from ArcMap. My updateParameters() consists of the following:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].value)
    #check = str(describe.shapeType)
    if describe.shapeType == 'Point':
        parameters[0].setWarningMessage('This is a point feature class')
    else:
        parameters[0].clearMessage()    

    if parameters[2].value == True:
        parameters[3].enabled = True
        parameters[4].enabled = True
        parameters[5].enabled = True

    else:       
        parameters[3].enabled = False
        parameters[4].enabled = False
        parameters[5].enabled = False       

    return
```

When I add a shapefile that I know in fact is a point, the tool does not output a warning. It simply accepts it without any feedback to the user.

Does it matter if the Describe.shapeType function has an output of Unicode?

I tested this through the ArcMap Python window with the following sequence of commands:

[image]

However, even if I try to convert the Describe.shapeType to a string, I still don't get a warning message. I've done the following tests:

1. Rather than checking for: if describe.shapeType == 'Point', I tried to check for: if describe.shapeType == u'Point', which would force it to check for a Unicode data type.
2. Converting the shapeType into a string via str(decribe.shapeType).
3. Using the encode method to change the Unicode into a sequence of ASCII characters: describe.shapeType.encode('ascii', 'ignore').

Hence, I've hit a wall once again.

Comment: I don't think you use AddWarning() there. You should probably use setErrorMessage() - check this link out: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002m000000

Comment: Regarding the confusion over parameter data types.. Where are you dragging and dropping the shapefile from? If your Data Type is DEShapefile, dragging and dropping the shapefile from ArcCatalog or browsing to the shapefile should definitely work. If you have added a shapefile to ArcMap and are dragging and dropping it from the ArcMap TOC - that will not work. It is now a feature layer and would require the GPFeatureLayer Data Type to be accepted as a parameter.

Comment: I am simply dragging and dropping the shapefiles from Windows Explorer directly into the ArcMap TOC. Does it matter if I drag and drop through Windows Explorer or ArcCatalog? Will it still convert the shapefile into a Feature layer once it is in the TOC?

Comment: I would use GPLayer, because that will accept shapefiles, geodatabase feature classes and layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it may be as simple as changing this line:

```
describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].value)
```

or maybe

```
describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].valueAsText)
```

Comment: Yes, I often forget to add the '.value'

Comment: Same here, although I have never done this in a .pyt, just in normal script tools.  I assume it behaves the same though.

Comment: Very good point! I have this in other areas of my code and did not think of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In his comment, @ian is correct about `AddWarning()` being useless outside of a tool's `execute()` method. I think the method you do want is [`setWarningMessage()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002m000000). Try this:

```
describe = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].value)
if describe.shapeType in ('Point', 'Multipoint'):  # catch point & multipoint
    parameters[0].setWarningMessage('This is a point feature class')
else:
    parameters[0].clearMessage()
```

Comment: You and @ian, you are both correct about the setWarningMessage() function. However, it looks like I'm now having issues getting this part to work. . . I'll update my question with my latest code and a screenshot. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is the enabling/disabling of parameters working as expected?

Comment: Yes it is. I even tried changing the order of the code so that the enabling would occur before the warning message, but it made no impact.

Comment: Put my code in the `updateMessages()` method instead of `updateParameters()` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Okay, now it works. Thank you everyone for all of your help!